# How to feed categorical features and labels into Tensorflow Time Series Forecasting?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, lstm, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

So, the objective I am chasing here is to do Time Series Forecasting using Tensorflow. My data is structured like this:

| timestamp | float64 | numerical |
| --- | --- | --- |
| feature a | float64 | numerical |
| feature b | float64 | numerical |
| feature c | string | categorical |
| target | string | categorical |

The issue I am facing is to properly input the categorical data columns I have.

---

Currently, my pipeline looks roughly like this:

1. Split the dataframe into training, validation and test

```
n = len(data)
train_df = data[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_df = data[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_df = data[int(n*0.9):]
```

2. Use `tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array` to preprocess the data

```
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
      data=data,
      targets=None,
      sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
      sequence_stride=1,
      shuffle=False,
      batch_size=32,)
```

3. Split the resulting `tf.dataset` into windows (closely following the tensorflow documentation for [time series forecasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series))
4. I have this simple model

```
lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
```

5. Then I compile and fit the model using my training and validation data

This does compile **if** I map the categorical data columns to `int` by myself (low cardinality). But that leaves the column in an ordinal state. If I don't do that, step 2 does not work.

---

Now, I looked into One Hot Encoding but could not figure out a way to implement this into my current pipeline. Maybe I completely misunderstood the process but the problem is that I need a dataframe with only `float32` values as input in step 2. Therefore, I would have to encode the data before that step. Every example for One Hot Encoding in Tensorflow I found performed the encoding within the model as an additional layer; not during the preprocessing stage.

I may be completely off, but I cannot figure out a way to fix that. I would be over the moon if somebody could point me towards the right direction.